# Update array of data using useState hook in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to update an array using `useState` hook after button click. I learnt that the `state` gets updated asynchronously. I tried to update the state by using an ES6 function inside `setMovies` but that does not seem to work. What should I be doing instead?

Could anyone please help?

```
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState('');

  ...


  const handleSearch = () => {
    return axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: url
      },
      params: {
        Title: movie,
      },
    })
      .then(({ data }) => {
        const { Hits } = data
        setMovies(Hits)
      })
  }

  const handleMovieChange = event => {
    setMovie(event.target.value)
  }
```

**UI**

```
<Grid container>
  <Grid item>
    <TextField onChange={handleMovieChange} label="Title" />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item>
    <Button  onClick={handleSearch}>
        Search
    </Button>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Code looks ok, if `Hits` is an array of movies. What is the issue?

Comment: For the first time, the `movies` array gets updated but next time, when i try to search with another value, the state still shows previous values :o @DrewReese

Comment: What search? What other value? What are you using to validate/verify state is previous value? It may help cut down on back and forth if you just post full and complete code, and include a set of reproduction steps.

Comment: could you show more code, like the part that you set `movie`

Comment: @hgb123 Just pasted more code in the question. Thanks!

Comment: So are you saying `Title: movie` is still the previous/old value? Do you clear `movie` state value when searching for movie hits? What button `type` does `Button` *actually* have (`type="submit"` is the default for button elements).

Comment: No, the `movies` value is still being same when I hit `Search`. `movie` that is coming from the Input `TextField` appears to be working correctly. So, first I search with `Lion King`, the data seem to be stored in `movies`. When I try to search again with `Avengers`, the `movies` still shows me `Lion King` movie data. @DrewReese

Comment: Have you double checked that you are sending updated requests (browser network tab in dev tools)? And if so, the request responses to ensure you are getting back what you expect? Can you repro this in a *running* codesandbox that we can live debug?

Comment: Yup, doing it now. Will post the link once done.@DrewReese

Comment: @DrewReese Created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-sea-we1s1?file=/src/App.js) I had to use a fake JSON api as i had secret API keys with my original code. Please use `1` or `2` or any number to `10` to get query new data and if you see the state, it still gives old data ( not the updated data )

Comment: Code appears to work correctly in sandbox. Though you can't console log the enqueued state update it will just log the state from the ***current*** render cycle, not what the state *will* be in the *next* render cycle. Is that what you are seeing? Try this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-platform-2tfvd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to see what I mean.

Comment: I see what you are saying. It appears to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. I guess it could be your return format has issue or `hits` instead of `Hits`. can you log to see if it is lower cases, that is something I have experienced before?

```
const { Hits, hits } = data;
console.log("Hits:", Hits, hits)
setMovies(Hits)
```

Comment: It is `Hits` itself. Problem is, the state does not get updated when I try to hit the API with another value. It is giving the previous state value when I log it.

Answer (score 0):

You could have missed the value for `TextField`, so it was not able to store the latest search term

```
<TextField value={movie} onChange={handleMovieChange} label="Title" />
```

Comment: This did not help as the `movie` will always change as I type anything in the `input`

Comment: @coderpc did you try to `console.log` the `movie` before any `handleSearch` request?